# Play Framework 2.5.x: Inject Environment in a Module

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice, playframework-2.5

Play app contains a custom module that initializes DB/Tables during the app start.
Starting with v2.5.x, the application mode(prod, test, dev) needs to be injected rather than using Current. I tried to apply the following inject parameters in the module code but saw compile errors.

```
trait MyInit[Environment] {
  val env: Environment
}

class MyInitClass[Environment] @Inject() (
  val env: Environment
) extends MyInit[Environment] {
  initializeDB()

  def initializeDB() = {
    Logger.info("MyINIT: Creating database...")
    MyDBService.createDatabase()
    Logger.info("MyINIT: Creating tables...")
    MyDBService.createTables()
  }
}

class MyModule(environment: Environment,
             configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
  def configure() = {
    bind[MyInit[Environment]].to[MyInitClass[Environment]].asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Is there a prescribed way of looking up Environment/Mode during module initialization in Play 2.5.x (Scala)?

Comment: What does the compile error say? Also it's not clear to me why you are using type parameter `Environment` in both trait and in the class extending the trait. It should work without the type parameter.

Comment: "Implementation limitation: Multiple argument lists on annotations are currently not supported."
I am trying to access/pass environment object to lookup the Mode so that I can initialize the desired db.

Comment: That's funny. How do you compile your code? I've seen a question with similar compile error on Stackoverflow literally yesterday or day before but it was removed soon for some reason. There the problem was with Intellij IDEA I suppose.

Comment: Anyway I think it's not eligible to pass dependencies to the `AbstractModule` constructor. You need to inject them to either constructor or fields of `MyInitClass`.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, you cannot bind generic type just using `bind` with type parameter. You need to use `TypeLiteral` https://thejavablog.wordpress.com/2008/11/17/how-to-inject-a-generic-interface-using-guice/

Comment: Now that you mentioned, It looks like IntelliJ weirdness. Also, thanks for the clarification on passing dependencies. Your suggestion(below) is the best fit solution. I will be posting a comment on the answer shortly after testing it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will rewrite your code to remove a small possible confusion here. This is exactly your code with a small rename of the type parameters:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.Environment
import play.api.Configuration
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

trait MyInit[T] {
  val env: T
}

class MyInitClass[T] @Inject() (val env: T) extends MyInit[T] {
  initializeDB()

  def initializeDB() = {
    Logger.info("MyINIT: Creating database...")
    MyDBService.createDatabase()
    Logger.info("MyINIT: Creating tables...")
    MyDBService.createTables()
  }
}
```

I renamed the type parameters to avoid confusion with `play.api.Environment`. I have the felling that this is not what you want, since `MyInitClass` does not actively receive an `play.api.Environment` anywhere.

If you want to do some initialization, why not go with something more simple and direct like this:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.{Configuration, Environment, Mode}

class DatabaseInitializerModule(
  environment: Environment,
  configuration: Configuration
) extends AbstractModule {

  def configure() = {
    environment.mode match {
      case Mode.Dev =>
        // Start dev database
      case Mode.Test =>
        // Start test database
      case Mode.Prod =>
        // Start prod database
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Edit:

A more idiomatic and recommended way to replace `GlobalSettings.onStart` is [described at the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/GlobalSettings#Scala):

> `GlobalSettings.beforeStart` and `GlobalSettings.onStart`: Anything that needs to happen on start up should now be happening in the constructor of a dependency injected class. A class will perform its initialisation when the dependency injection framework loads it. If you need eager initialisation (because you need to execute some code *before* the application is actually started), [define an eager binding](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings).

So, we can rewrite your code to be something like this:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.{Environment, Mode}
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

class DatabaseInitializer @Inject()(environment: Environment) {
  environment.mode match {
    case Mode.Dev =>
    // Start dev database
    case Mode.Test =>
    // Start test database
    case Mode.Prod =>
    // Start prod database
  }
}

class DatabaseInitializerModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[DatabaseInitializer]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Notice how I've removed the `trait` since it is not adding any value here.

Comment: The parameter renaming still showed up as an error in IntelliJ. But the procedure below is more straight forward and just works. However I wonder if there is a prescribed design pattern in Play 2.5.x for initialization based on mode using DI. I will be marking this as the answer in case such a solution is unnecessary. Thanks!

Comment: I've renamed the type parameters just to avoid confusion between its name and `play.api.Environment`. I was under the impression that you were confusing the concepts here. Anyway, the most recommended way to replace/remove GlobalSettings is described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/GlobalSettings#Scala. I will edit my answer to adapt your code to something that looks more idiomatic to me.

Comment: Yes, the trait usage is redundant. In my case, I added a line which sets the mode directly in the db connector object right inside configure(). This way, the MyInitClass stays exactly the same and the call to initialize db will be on the actual db init object with the mode already set. However, I marked your answer as the accepted one. Thanks!